# API results fill all nested unnecessary class in Json (repeated parents)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

in my net core 2.2 API project has some repeted class issue.
I have a class has own class itself, for parent. I get them from repository only one parent but it also automatically fill parent's parents. I just need first, not others. It increases my json size too much.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? ParentUserId { get; set; }
    public User ParentUser { get; set; }
}
```

Json:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "firstName": "Jane",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "userId": 2,
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "parentUserId": 1,
      "parentUser": {
        "userId": 1,
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe"
      }
    },
    {
      "userId": 3,
      "firstName": "Test",
      "lastName": "Test",
      "parentUserId": 1,
      "parentUser": {
        "userId": 1,
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe"
      }
    },
    {
      "userId": 4,
      "firstName": "Test 2",
      "lastName": "Idfour",
      "parentUserId": 2,
      "parentUser": {
        "userId": 2,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "parentUserId": 1,
        "parentUser": {
          "userId": 1,
          "firstName": "Jane",
          "lastName": "Doe"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

UserId 2 and 3 is normal, but 4 has parent inside the parent, what I want is

```
{
      "userId": 4,
      "firstName": "Test 2",
      "lastName": "Idfour",
      "parentUserId": 2,
      "parentUser": {
        "userId": 2,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
      }
    }
```

--- Edit ---
@Zhi Lv solution is working, but I have an array and need to delete it.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? ParentUserId { get; set; }
    public User ParentUser { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserFavorite> UserFavorites { get; set; }
}

public class Favorite
{
    public int FavoriteId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserFavorite
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int FavoriteId { get; set; }
}
```

In this case I have select inside query select and it causes a lot of sql select. What should I do?

Comment: up? ............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get them from repository only one parent but it also automatically
> fill parent's parents.

From the Json result, I guess perhaps in your web API, you directly query the user table and return the data, so it will eager loading the related data.

You could try to change the query statement as below, in the select statement create new instance:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ReturnData Get()
    {
        //var result = _context.Users.ToList();
        //query data base
        var result = _context.Users.Select(c => new User
        {
            UserId = c.UserId,
            FirstName = c.FirstName,
            LastName = c.LastName,
            ParentUserId = c.ParentUserId,
            ParentUser = c.ParentUser ==null? null: new User()
            {
                UserId = c.ParentUser.UserId,
                FirstName =c.ParentUser.FirstName,
                LastName = c.ParentUser.LastName,
                ParentUserId = c.ParentUserId
            }
        }).ToList();  
        ReturnData returnData = new ReturnData() { users = result };
        return returnData;
    }
```

Code in the ReturnData:

```
public class ReturnData
{
    public List<User> users { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the result like this:

```
        {
            "users": [
                {
                "userId": 1,
                    "firstName": "Jane",
                    "lastName": "Doe",
                    "parentUserId": null,
                    "parentUser": null
                },
                {
                "userId": 2,
                    "firstName": "John",
                    "lastName": "Doe",
                    "parentUserId": 1,
                    "parentUser": {
                    "userId": 1,
                        "firstName": "Jane",
                        "lastName": "Doe",
                        "parentUserId": 1,
                        "parentUser": null
                    }
            },
                {
                "userId": 3,
                    "firstName": "Test",
                    "lastName": "Test",
                    "parentUserId": 1,
                    "parentUser": {
                    "userId": 1,
                        "firstName": "Jane",
                        "lastName": "Doe",
                        "parentUserId": 1,
                        "parentUser": null
                    }
            },
                {
                "userId": 4,
                    "firstName": "Test 2",
                    "lastName": "IdFour",
                    "parentUserId": 2,
                    "parentUser": {
                    "userId": 2,
                        "firstName": "John",
                        "lastName": "Doe",
                        "parentUserId": 2,
                        "parentUser": null
                    }
            }
            ]
        }
```

About the property which contains a null value, you could remove them when display them.

Comment: this works thanks, but what about I have an array inside class? (edit question)

Answer (score 0):

if you want a really specific return, like exclude self reference is a particular api, maybe you could do this way around.

```
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var res = await _repo.GetData();
    return Json(res , new JsonSerializerSettings(){ ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
}
```

this return Json(), will override your global configuration jsonserializersetting and set reference loop handling to ignore, so it may result what you needed

Comment: Actuall I have it in startup and added for return likde this, but it  did not work. I guess it is about to prevent if it loops itself.